# In D3 How to enable mouse over event for current particular path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was creating a world map using `d3.js`.In that map i need to bind the `mouseover` event for every country.

**For example:** If i `mouseover` the india i need to change the Fill(Background) color for india only.

I implemented the `mouseover` event.But my problem is whenever i `mouseover` over the country(India) that function effecting all the countries.I mean fill color effecting all the countries.But it need to effect only current country.

I tried using `this` also but no luck for me.

```
.on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
```

Please help any one to solve my problem.

### My Full Code

```
     var width = 1000,
        height = 500;

    var projection = d3.geo.robinson()
        .scale(150)
    //.translate(100,100)
    .precision(.5);

    var path = d3.geo.path()
    //  .attr("class","path")
        .projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select('#'+id)
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("style", "background:" + json.bc);


    //shape
    d3.json("world.json", function(error, world) {

         svg                            
            .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries))
            .append("path")             
            .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");})
            .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
            .attr("style", "fill:" + json.cbc)          
            .attr("class", "country")
            .attr("d", path)

            ;
    });
```

**Before mouseover**

[image: Before MouseOver]

**After MouseOver**

[image: After mouseOver]

Comment: You're creating a single path for all countries, so what you're trying to do is impossible with your current code. You'll have to create the map in a way that each country is a separate path.

Comment: ok @Lars kotthoff Thanks for answer.Am new to d3. Can you give me a start. I mean how to create a seperate path for each countries?

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4180634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
 svg                            
  .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries))
  .append("path")
...
```

says --> I have one piece of data, draw me a path from it.

Change it up to this:

```
svg.selectAll(".countries")
  .data(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.countries).features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  ...
```

which says --> I have multiple data (features), bind the data to my selection (selectAll) and draw me a path for each component.

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/39u4X0gTMQMhAsUsJP9m?p=preview).